# Running "ip | grep | awk" within a sed replacement

Tags: awk, sed, raspberry-pi, grep, ip

Problem Set (Raspberry Pi OS):
I have a file `example.conf` that contains a line `IPv4addr=XXXXX`.  I am attempting to change this to the IP that is generated the in the command

```
ipTest=$(ip --brief a show | grep eth0 | awk '{ print $3 }')
```

I want to automate this file change during a script `install.sh`, the line I am attempting is:

```sh
IPtest=$(ip --brief a show | grep eth0 | awk '{ print $3 }')
sudo sed -e "/IPv4addr/s/[^=]*$/$IPtest/" example.conf
```

Returns error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'
```

A simple line in that code works, such as `SimpleTest='Works'`

Any thoughts?  I am open to other solutions as well, however I am not an experienced linux user so I am using the tools I know to work with other problem sets.

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: consider updating the question with the output from `typeset -p IPtest` (to show us what's in the variable); a sample from `example.conf` would also be of benefit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$IPtest` contains the `/` character; try something like this:

```
IPtest=$(ip --brief a show | grep eth0 | awk '{ print $3 }')
```

```
sudo sed -e '/IPv4addr/s@[^=]*$@'"$IPtest"'@' example.conf
```

Comment: Nice answer. You could add, maybe, that the sed command will not modify the `example.conf` file without the `-i` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your variable and allow `awk` to do the job of `grep` at the same time

```
IPtest=$(ip --brief a s | awk '/eth0/{print $3}')
```

Using `sed` grouping and back referencing

```
sed -i.bak "s|\([^=]*.\).*|\1$IPtest|" example.conf
```